# Gnuplot plot 2D matrix with image, get xrange

Tags: gnuplot

When I plot an 1D function, and then I choose an xy-range in the plot with the mouse (~zooming) I can access the selected x-y range with `print GPVAL_X_MIN`; `print GPVAL_X_MAX`; `print GPVAL_Y_MIN` and `print GPVAL_Y_MAX`
I want to do the same thing when I plot 2D matrix with

```
plot 'datafile.dat' matrix using 1:2:3 with image
```

but after the plotting, the "manual zoom" with the mouse has no effect on the value of `GPVAL_X_MIN` and the others.

Could you help me?

I am using version 4.6.3 (Build System: Linux i686), with `qt` `terminal`.

**UPDATE:** the same effect (no-effect) with `wxt` or `x11` terminal.

Comment: I just tried with 5.0.1 on x64 with the qt terminal and it worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to `Gnuplot 5.0.3` solved the problem (it seems that is a bug in `4.6.3`).

Thank you
[Gavin Portwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2616417/gavin-portwood)!